# Dependecy Property at design time

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

It works only at runtime. If I bind new InputNodeRed() to the MyNode's Node control shows the static resource only when the program is running and not at design time. What am I doing wrong. (see converter code comment for details)

Custom Control Node

```
public class Node : Control
{
    static Node()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Node), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Node)));
    }

    public BaseData.Node MyNode
    {
        get { return (BaseData.Node)GetValue(MyNodeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyNodeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyNodeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyNode", typeof(BaseData.Node), typeof(Node), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

Node converter

```
 public class NodeTypeToDataTemplateConverter :IValueConverter
 {
    public DataTemplate RedNode { get; set; }


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //if(value == null) //binding new InputNodeRed(), at design time value == null
        //    return null;
        if (value is BaseData.InputNodeRed || value is BaseData.OutputNodeRed)
            return RedNode;

        return null;
    }
 }
```

I have putted this code `if(value == null) return null;` only to check if the value is null, and it returns null at design time.

Node template

```
<local:NodeTypeToDataTemplateConverter x:Key="NodeTypeConverter"
                 RedNode="{StaticResource RedNode}" />

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Node}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type local:Node}">
                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{Binding MyNode, Converter={StaticResource NodeTypeConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Data classes

```
abstract public class Node { } 

abstract public class InputNode : Node { } 

abstract public class OutputNode : Node { } 

public class OutputNodeRed : OutputNode { }

public class InputNodeRed : InputNode { }
```

[link to photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMgml.png)
[image: photo]

Clearly biniding works, but not at design time.

Comment: Can you show how you're binding the new InputNodeRed() to the Node control?

Comment: Your class design is really awkward. Remove all custom controls and converters and use simple `DataTemplate`s for this.

Comment: Yeah I know it is awkward. Like this `<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource RedNode}"/>` ?